# Change one of the line styles in ggplot2 graph with long data format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in the melted form

```
b <- data.table(q = seq(5), 
                A = rnorm(5, mean=1, sd=1), 
                B = rnorm(5, mean=1.5, sd=1), 
                C = rnorm(5, mean=2, sd=1))
longb <- melt.data.table(b, id.vars = 'q', measure.vars = c(names(b)[-1]))
```

The to draw three lines one has to do:

```
ggplot(data = longb, aes(x = q, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

I wander if it is possible to change one of the series (say C) from being line to being dotted graph (like `geom_point()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
ggplot(data = longb, aes(x = q, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = (variable == "C"))) +
  guides(linetype = "none")
```

[image]

Or better:

```r
ggplot(data = longb, aes(x = q, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = variable)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,1,3))
```

[image]

Or well?:

```r
ggplot(data = longb[variable != "C"], aes(x = q, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = longb[variable == "C"], aes(x = q, y = value))
```

[image]

Comment: this is good solution, but only changes line style. Is it possible to have it like dots at the data point only (may be some option in guides)? I had in mind something related to geom_point. If there will be no better answer I will take this